# How to get value of `var` inside return of React component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the value of `googleToken` inside a `<div>` in the `return` of my React Component. The value is already updated, but it's the initial state here in the `return`, therefore, it always shows `null`

```js
const Layout = props => {
 
  let googleToken = null;

  useEffect( () => {
    fetchGoogleToken();
  }, [])

  const fetchGoogleToken = async () => {
    await api
      .get("/google_token")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('google_token: ' + response.data.google_token);
        googleToken = response.data.google_token;
        console.log('google_token updated: ' + googleToken);
      })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  const getGoogleToken = (res) => {
    
    console.log(res);
    setGoogleToken(res.accessToken);
    saveGoogleTokenInDB();
    
  };

  const saveGoogleTokenInDB = async () => {
    await api
      .post("/fit-auth", {google_token : googleToken})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

return (       
  <div className={classes.googleButton} style={{display: googleToken === null ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
    <h3>{googleToken}</h3>
  <div/>
}
```

Any ideas on why I can't get the updated value?

Comment: This is not enough code to debug this issue.

Comment: already Edited!

Comment: googleToken is getting a new value on each render.  Look into using `useState` to preserve its value across renders, and `useEffect` to do your initial fetching.

Comment: The call from `fetchGoogleToken()` is already preserving it, I believe

Comment: But if you use useState and set the token in state, you can trigger a re-render with that new value.

Comment: I was using `useState` but it wasnt working with the api call because `useState`is async

Comment: Because `fetchGoogleToken` is async, you will *never* have a value on at least the first render of the component. As other comments mentioned, you'll want to use `useState` to store the value once you get it -- just have a contingency for rendering before the value is filled in.

Comment: `useState` is not async as such. React does batch state changes when it can but in this case it won't. You're perception of asyncronous state here is that you were likely setting the state within a promise callback.

Comment: I defenitly was! where should I set the state then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right to use useEffect hook for fetching. But the result must be kept into state. And when you ask react to update state, you can not watch changes on the next line of code using console.log because setState is async function and it will be executed later on.

```
  // this will never work as you might be expected:
  setState(newState)
  console.log(state)
```

To catch state updates always use useEffect hook as in example below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state)
  }, [state])
```

Also, avoid using inline styles for showing / hiding your components. Check the official [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) recommendations.
The final code is going to look like this:

```
const Layout = props => {
  const [googleToken, setGoogleToken] = useState(null)

  useEffect( () => {
    fetchGoogleToken();
  }, [])

  // you can watch how state changes only using useEffect:
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('google_token updated: ' + googleToken)
  }, [googleToken])

  const fetchGoogleToken = async () => {
    await api
      .get("/google_token")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('google_token: ' + response.data.google_token);
        setGoogleToken(response.data.google_token);
      })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  // conditional rendering:
  if (!googleToken) return <span>Fetching token...</span>
  return (
    <div className={classes.googleButton}>
      <h3>{googleToken}</h3>
    <div/>
  )
}
```

Hope you will find this helpful.

Comment: Hello! It was very helpful, but the call from `getGoogleTokenInDB` isn't working anymore! I updated the code with this part.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when the value of googleToken is updated the component is not notified about this. Since the component is not notified about the change it still believes that the value is still the initial value and it does need to change anything in DOM.

To solve this issue try using states or just force a rerender once the function is executed.

Comment: I tryed using states but it did not updated the value in any case